# Parallax background image that isn't exactly fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to create a subtle parallax effect on a background image inside a div. I have used the following markup and CSS..

HTML

```
<div class="widget bg-parallax" style="background-image: url(~~set dynamically~~)"></div>
```

CSS

```
.widget {
    height:500px;
    position: relative;
}
.bg-parallax {
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

But this creates a background image that is fully stationary as the page scroll.

**I would like for the background to scroll but at a much slower rate than the page.**

Is this achievable with pure CSS? If not, can anyone point me in the right direction with JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this. Yes, it is achievable with pure CSS.

```
.forefront-element {
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(999px) scale(.7);
transform: translateZ(999px) scale(.7);
z-index: 1;
 }

 .base-element {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
z-index: 4;
 }

.background-element {
-webkit-transform: translateZ(-999px) scale(2);
transform: translateZ(-999px) scale(2);
z-index: 3;
 }
```

This controls the height. The negative  Z values make it go slower when scrolling.

Comment: thank you for the reply. this seems to achieve what Im asking. could you please specify what the "forefront, base, and background" elements are explicitly

Comment: Forefront brings an element to the front

Comment: Background targets the background of the page(even if you dont have one set).

Comment: "<base> element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document. There can be only one <base> element in a document. " from Mozilla Development Network.

Comment: @yevg this answer your question?

Comment: it definitely helps me understand the methodology but still a bit confused about how to implement. assuming I have a div who's background-image I want to scroll slower than the the rest of the page, would that div be the "background-element"?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code in w3schools.com, yours is slightly different http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: this code shows how to achieve what I already have above. I would like to a background that is NOT fixed, but rather scrolls at a slower rate than the page